# NameError when trying to pass variable across functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that can respond to user input, but emails me when it doesn't know how to respond.

```
import time
import smtplib
import random

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def void():
    print("You find your self hanging in the void.")
    response = input("What do you want to do?")
    if response == "dance":
        dance()
    else:
        bug()
def dance():
    print("You dance your heart out like nobody is watching")
    void()

#if the thing breaks
def bug():
    print(response + " will be in the next release!")

    FROM ='simulation@gendale.net'

    TO = ["sweeney@roerick.me"]

    SUBJECT = "new command request"

    TEXT = response

    message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s

""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('mail.gendale.net')
    server.login('simulation@gendale.net', 'XXXXXXXXX')
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit
    sys.exit()
def credits():
    print("Welcome to the Everything Simulator.")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Brought to you by Gendale Entertainment")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Written and coded by Roerick Sweeney")
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    void()
credits()
```

When I run this script, I get the error: "NameError: name 'response' is not defined" As far as I can understand it, my 'response' variable is somehow getting lost. The smtp script works fine when I call the string myself, but I would like to pass 'response' from void() to bug(). I'm using python3.

Comment: Consider editing the question.  As it stands, it seems to be to questions.  If you replace "...getting lost." with "...getting lost when I call bug() from void()." and eliminating the reference ", but I would like to pass 'response' from void() to bug()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how variables are [scoped in python](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-17/python-scope-basics), in order for `response` to be defined within the `bug()` and `dance()` functions you need to pass it in from `void()`.

For example:

```
def void():
    print("You find your self hanging in the void.")
    response = input("What do you want to do?")
    if response == "dance":
        dance(response)
    else:
        bug(response)

def dance(response):
    print("You dance your heart out like nobody is watching")
    void()

def bug(response):
    print(response + " will be in the next release!")

    FROM ='simulation@gendale.net'

    TO = ["sweeney@roerick.me"]

    SUBJECT = "new command request"

    TEXT = response

    message = ""
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks for also providing a great resource on scope.

Comment: @user46593 No problem. If I answered your question, can you please click the check mark next to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refer a variable (response) which is defined in function (Void()).

U need to create a global variable to refer it in different functions.

```
def void():
    global response
    response = raw_input('What do u want:\n')

    if response == 'dance':
        Dance()
    else:
        Bug()

def Dance(response):
    print("You dance your heart out like nobody is watching")
    void()

def Bug():
    global response
    print ">>> Response is :", response
    FROM ='simulation@gendale.net'

    TO = ["sweeney@roerick.me"]

    SUBJECT = "new command request"

    TEXT = response

    message = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    void()
```